# Net core api called many times

Tags: asp.net-core, nginx, architecture, asp.net-core-webapi, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have a trouble with my e-commerce application.
Let me explain base architecture.
we have 6 web servers behind the cloudflare, after that nginx undertakes reverse proxy role. Web and web api are two seperate application and host on every single web server.

Here is my problem,
When users request the site very havily some apis called multiple times in miliseconds by same client.

For ie clear basket method called multiple times in 1 milisecond.

I didnt use async pattern. Onyl api calls are async but they are very simple.

Here is ny api caller helper method

```
 public async Task<string> GetString(string url)
    {
        var client = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
        //   var client = new HttpClient();
        var uri = new Uri(url);
        var response = await client.GetAsync(uri);
        var responseData =await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        return responseData;
    }
```

At behind(api) I used EF CORE 5 and sometimes I have to run some stored procedures with ExecuteSqlRaw method.

Here is some sql log for delete sp basket

```
2021-12-29 20:00:35.547
2021-12-29 20:00:35.407
```

Can anyone suggest some inspirations?

Thanks

Comment: You say "clear basket method called multiple times in 1 milisecond", but your sql log clearly shows its in the same second, with 140ms in time difference. That is maybe possible by hitting F5 like a crazy, or a second/thid call on the same page to that function. That last one could be a mistake or by design.

Comment: Are you storing the current state of the customers basket in the database? It this necessary? I think that this can be stored in the users session, e.g. on the client. In addition, you could also read this article about caching: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/response?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: can you more details on the UI website a bit. Typically i have faced this issue when multiple events in website trigger the client to call the web API. quick solution for this it to cache the response in client for say, 1 sec, so that any retrys in 1sec wont reach the webapi. But this is just a quick fix for GET methods. Real fix is to stop multiple trigger from the website reaching the web API.

Comment: UI calls with $.get and I change it to $.ajax. 
And @Martin yes I must store at the database cause I have a very high traffic. So prevent multiple sales in last stocks I must reserve my stocks.

Comment: I tried to call my api multiple times with debug console on chrome. For ie in console window I wrote my function 20 times and press enter. I didnt see any unexpected behavior. My sp called 1 times. There is something which I miss.